# Add constructed command to bash history

Tags: bash

I made a bash function which retrieves a list of cron tasks (from Magento). I can search through that (filtered) list immediately using FZF and it runs the selected cron using another command through xargs. The function is as follows:

`crf () { magerun2 sys:cr:li | grep -E '\*|-' | grep -v '+' | awk '{print $2}' | fzf --query=$1 | xargs magerun2 sys:cr:run; }`

Is it possible to add the command which just ran through xargs to the history so when i press the `up` arrow it will show the command which has just passed through xargs?

I'm running on a Macbook Pro, using bash version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0) and tmux 3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using `history -s`

```
$ history -s my command
<PRESS UP KEY>
$ my command
```

**EDIT:**
So in your case itll be something like

```
crf () { 

CHRON=$(magerun2 sys:cr:li | grep -E '\*|-' | grep -v '+' | awk '{print $2}' | fzf --query=$1 ) 

for item in $CHRON ; do
    history -s $item
    magerun2 sys:cr:run $item
done 
}
```

Comment: Updated with further info

Comment: Works like a charm! I tried putting that `history -s` within the single line command earlier, some form of multi commands with xargs but that didn't work. However, your solution works just as expected.

Comment: @Kozie, fantastic. Please mark answers as correct if this has helped. Thanks.